# "library openssl was not set python depends on it, please enable" while compiling Visit Visualization Tool

Tags: openssl, opensuse

I am building the visualization software Visit from source on OpenSUSE Leap 15.0. Unfortunately, I get this error message:

```
Processing bsd license.
Setting VisIt info...
[build_visit invocation arguments] 
g++ version 7.4.1
Fortran support for thirdparty libraries disabled.
enabling any dependent libraries
ERROR: library openssl was not set python depends on it, please enable
Error in build process.
```

Unfortunately, an Installation of the OpenSSL devel package did not solve the issue. Can anybody explain why I am getting this error and how I can fix it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

So if anybody tries the same: use the following options when calling the build script.

`--openssl --zlib`